# Old containers not terminating on deploy

Tags: digital-ocean, dokku

We deploy node processes to DigitalOcean via Dokku. We have a strange problem where each deploy leaves duplicate docker containers open - it doesn't appear that Dokku is terminating them and so we end up with lots of duplicate processes.

How does Dokku manage the docker containers on deploy? Should it not be killing them? The git hook always says "Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds", but that never happens...

Here's the Dokku version info:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:54:52 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:54:52 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? This still happens over here with Dokku 0.12.4.